# Minimum width/height in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I set minimum width or height for React Native component?

In css, I can use min-width/min-height

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#content

There is no minWidth/minHeight on react-native docs

Comment: What is your use case for min-width and min-height? Maybe you can set width/height dynamically, ensuring it's never less than the target minimums

Comment: I want to set min-width for button, I want a button with a min width even its text is very short

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**minHeight**, **maxHeight**, **minWidth** and **maxWidth** properties are supported as of react-native version **0.29.0** for [iOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/78b892906b00932447e86465bec4613c118f01fc) and [Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/1579a72ca6db1490519e171d56d9d000c73e3bcb).

Here is the **maxHeight** description from [react-native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#maxheight). This description also applies for other min/max style properties.

> maxHeight is the maximum height for this component, in
>   logical pixels.
>
> It works similarly to max-height in CSS, but in React Native you must
>   use points or percentages. Ems and other units are not supported.
>
> See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height for
>   more details.

A dummy example:

```js
<View
  style={{
    minWidth: '20%',
    maxWidth: 500,
    minHeight: '10%',
    maxHeight: 150,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is outdated now, use halilb's answer.

<strike>I solved this by using the `onLayout` prop, its very easy:</strike>

Example:

**Step 1: I create a prop in our state that will be holding the current height of the image called** `curImgHeight`.

```js
constructor(){
  super(props);
  this.state={curImgHeight:0}
}
```

**Step 2: Use the prop in any `View` or `Element` that supports the `onLayout` prop.**

Here I use it with an `Image`. Then all we have to do is, change that state property whenever the actual image height is than our minimum height.

```js
render(){
  <Image
    source={{uri: "https://placehold.it/350x150"}}
    resizeMode='cover'

    style={[styles.image, {height:(this.state.curImgHeight<=0?null:this.state.curImgHeight)}]}

    onLayout={(e)=>{
      let {height} = e.nativeEvent.layout;
      let minimumImgHeight = 400; //We set the minimum height we want here.
      if(height<= minimumImgHeight){ //Whenever the real height of the image is less than the minimum height
        this.setState({curImgHeight:minimumImgHeight}); //just change the curImgHeight state property to the minimum height.
      }
    }}
  />
}
```

Thats how I solved it for me.

p.s: During my search I found that react-native unofficially supports `minHeight` and `maxHeight` but only for iOS and not for Android. I wouldn't dare using them though. The above code works well and gives me control.

Comment: This solution flicker since setState is async

Comment: @ptomasroos You can turn it to sync using the async/await statements like so:    
https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/c8b90988d02eaaf82d4da8fc407ba6a9

Comment: Thanks. Good call but since setState won't be reflected sync this will flicker as in the rendering roundtrip. Since a call to setState is truly async before its visible

Comment: minHeight and maxHeight seem to be supported in React-Native already

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work out the solution for you. Here's a working demo...
https://rnplay.org/apps/vaD1iA

And here are the key parts.

First, you pull in the device dimensions...

```js
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var {
  width,
  height
} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Here's the button component, which uses the device width as the basis for the button's with

```js
const Button = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={[styles.button,{width: width - 20}]}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
});
```

Then, as you can see here, the button width will be the same regardless of label content width.

[image]

Comment: There's a github issue filed on this. Here's a link for the latest status (spoiler alert: it's been retracted for now) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/4183#issuecomment-158862314

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```js
_getButtonStyle() {
  var style = {height:36,padding:8}

  if(this.props.buttonText.length < 4){
    style.width = 64
  }
  return style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use minHeight or flexBasis - it is similar.