# React-native - Pinterest style with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, react-native

I use react-native for pinterest style app. I wrote this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ListView,
  View,
  ToolbarAndroid,
  Image,
} = React;

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var w = Dimensions.get('window');
var r = (w.width / 2) / 500;

var REQUEST_URL = 'http://www.wisgoon.com/api/v6/post/user/8090/';


var new_wisgoon = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetchData(REQUEST_URL);
  },

  fetchData: function(url) {
    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.objects), 
        loaded: true,
      });
    })
    .done();
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView width={w.width} height={5500}>
      <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderPost}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.items}
      style={styles.itemsBox}
      />
      </ScrollView>
      );
  },

  renderLoadingView: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>
      Loading posts...
      </Text>
      </View>
      );
  },

  checkThumb: function(obj){
    if (obj) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  renderPost: function(post) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.item, {width: (w.width / 2) - 7}]}>
        <Image source={{uri: post.images.low_resolution.url}} 
        style={[{ width: post.images.low_resolution.width * r, height: post.images.low_resolution.height * r }]} 
        />

        <View style={styles.post_text_box}>
          <Text style={styles.post_text}>{post.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    itemsBox: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        height: 3500,
    },
    items: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flex: 1,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    item: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#555',
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    post_text_box: {
        padding: 20,
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('new_wisgoon', () => new_wisgoon);
```

Result is fine, but ListView just shows 11 from 20 posts:
[image]

I guess it's about height in itemBox. When I set itemBox height 3500, below image displays and when I remove that, images lists one by one like row.
What can I do?

```
itemsBox: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    height: 3500,
},
```

Comment: Try using flex:1 on ScrollView and ListView. You should not have to specify the height.

Comment: @NaderDabit Don't changes

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you be more specific about the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B tnx for answer, in API request, response contains 20 row, but ListView displays 11 row, I guess some rows are hide or something! Like `overflow:hidden` in css!

Comment: have you tried `min-height` instead of `height`?

Comment: `min-height` for which element? for `itemsBox` ? Yes, I tried. doesn't works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33427923/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B my problem is not height. when I set more height for itemBox, each images inserted in a row.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with React Native to provide more specific feedback. Sorry, and good luck.

Comment: I can't see all of your code to know the issue, but I've set up a gist for someone else to solve a similar issue, maybe it will help https://gist.github.com/dabit3/72138f22120f835dfb92

Comment: @chalist It's awesome, does it work now ?

Comment: Any solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two columns in RN FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330207/two-columns-in-rn-flatlist)

Answer (score -2):

You can using React-Native GirdView:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gridview