# Two columns in RN FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I list 2 columns in a React Native Flatlist, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting a variable height layout? Also, what have you done to approach this problem? There are other similar questions with answers, but I cannot tell what is different since yours is so sparse on details. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "variable height layout" does not make a difference. "numColumns" creates a grid.

Answer (score 16):

Just pass the prop [numColumns](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns) to your FlatList component.

Comment: I thought that too but when I read up on the prop, I saw this: **Items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported.** It looks like OP is attempting such a layout so this wouldn't work unless there some styling trickery that can be done.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Although the example image has different heights, it isn't mentioned in the question that it would require to have different heights, it just asks how to get two columns in a FlatList component. I think that the question author doesn't know about this prop.

Comment: Agreed. I'll flag and comment to ask for clarification.

Comment: "numColumns" creates a grid.

Comment: note to self: making inner items `flex:1` will fill the width

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one of two ways. First the straight forward way is to create 2 FlatList columns with flex layout and distribute your data between them like so:

Assuming you have `style` and `data` defined

```
const style={
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 400
  },
  column: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1
  }
}

const data = [
  { key: 'A' },
  { key: 'B' },
  { key: 'C' },
  { key: 'D' },
  { key: 'E' },
  { key: 'F' },
  { key: 'G' },
  { key: 'H' },
  { key: 'I' }
];
```

*You can do this*

```
render() {
  //Split the data (however you want it)
  const column1Data = data.filter((item, i) => i%2 === 0);
  const column2Data = data.filter((item, i) => i%2 === 1);

  return (
    <View style={ style.container }>

      <View style={ style.column }>
        <Text>Column 1</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={ column1Data }
          renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
            <View style={ style.item }>
              <Text>{ item.key }</Text>
            </View>
          ) }
        />
      </View>

      <View style={ style.column }>
        <Text>Column 2</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={ column2Data }
          renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
            <View style={ style.item }>
              <Text>{ item.key }</Text>
            </View>
          ) }
        />
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}
```

**The issue** there is that both lists are independent and would render a bad mobile experience. A better way would be to group your data and render a single column FlatList so your content is unified.

**First** you would need a function to group your data into 'rows' of data

```
  //The key here is grouping the data to be in one row together
  const groupData = (items, groupLen) => {
    const groups = [];
    let i = 0;

    while (i < items.length) {
      groups.push(items.slice(i, i += groupLen));
    }

    return groups;
  };
```

*Then do this...*

```
render() {
  const groupedItems = groupData(data, 2)

  return (
    <View style={ style.column }>

        <Text>Main Column</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={ groupedItems }
          renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
            <View style={ style.row }>
              {
                /* item is really the group of items in the row */
                item.map((singleItem, index ) => (
                  <Text style={ style.item }>{ singleItem.key }</Text>
                ))
              }
            </View>
          ) }
        />

    </View>
  );
}
```

You will likely need to fiddle with the styling to get it like you want, but you get the idea :)

Comment: FlatList does not support items that are different heights like the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a long time to figure this out, but this can in fact be achieved without using any external libraries. The trick is to use negative margin.

The negative margin will be applied in the VirtualizedList prop CellRendererComponent in order to get it to work properly on Android.

The JSX:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        CellRendererComponent={({ children, item, ...props }) => {
            return (
                <View {...props} style={{ marginTop: item.marginTop }}>
                    {children}
                </View>
            )
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            const { source: source1, height: height1, marginTop: marginTop1 } = item.image1;
            const { source: source2, height: height2, marginTop: marginTop2 } = item.image2;
            return (
                <View style={Style.viewRow}>
                    <Image source={source1} style={[styles.image, { height: height1, marginTop: marginTop1 }]} />
                    <Image source={source2} style={[styles.image, { height: height2, marginTop: marginTop2 }]} />
                </View>
            )
        }}
    />
</View>
```

The data:

```
const source = { uri: 'https://placekitten.com/160/300' };

const data = [
    {
        marginTop: 0,
        image1: { source, height: 300, marginTop: 0 },
        image2: { source, height: 250, marginTop: 0 }
    },
    {
        marginTop: -50,
        image1: { source, height: 290, marginTop: 50 },
        image2: { source, height: 300, marginTop: 0 }
    },
    {
        marginTop: -40,
        image1: { source, height: 250, marginTop: 40 },
        image2: { source, height: 350, marginTop: 0 }
    }
];
```

The styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      flex: 1
   },
   flatList: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
   },
   viewRow: {
      flexDirection: 'row'
   },
   image: {
      width: '50%',
      resizeMode: 'cover'
   }
});
```

Do note that arranging the images in the array properly is up to you - always place the taller image in the shorter side, and make sure to calculate the height difference and keep track of it. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `numColumns`

```
<FlatList 
 data={albums}
 renderItem={({item}) => <></>}
 numColumns={2}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-native` standard style is `flexDirection: 'col'`, which means the elements are arranged from top to bottom. To change this (right to left) you should set style to `flexDirection: 'row'`.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <FlatList
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  />
  <FlatList
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `react-native-scroll-lazy` instead of ScrollView, Previously I had problems like the above, I have solved them, and wrote a library to share with people who have the same problem.

Comment: Previously when you posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63369275/7508700) on multiple questions, a moderator deleted most of them because, in general, if an identical answer can resolve multiple questions you should flag them as duplicate and not post the same answer, especially [if you are posting answers in order to promote your own library](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270841/7508700).