# React Native - Is it possible to create a similar grid with Flatlist? (shown in the picture)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I would like the grid shown in the picture, but the shape of the grid changes after turning the page. Possible? How?

i built the first page with scrollview.

```
 <ScrollView
                ref={(scrollView) => {
                    this.scrollView = scrollView;
                }}
                horizontal={true}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                decelerationRate={0}
                snapToInterval={width - 60}
                snapToAlignment={"center"}
                contentInset={{
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 30,
                }}>
                <View style={[styles.containerFlex, {
                    width: width - 60,
                    flexDirection: "column"
                }]}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red", flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></View>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'purple'}}></View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: "darkorange"}}/>
                    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: "green"}}/>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

I would like a different layout when turning pages. (Second picture)

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

Comment: You will have to use scrollView for that with flex

Comment: Your answer is maybe here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330207/two-columns-in-rn-flatlist